# Views: Ranking users by pageviews this month, last month

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view to rank Users by the total numbers of pageviews their nodes have received. I now want to clone that view and create 2 blocks:

1. Totals views their nodes have received this month
2. Total view their nodes received last month.

I have tried using contextual filters and I can create a view to show total pageviews in a date range, but, that would mean me updating the filter every month. Is there another way I can do this? I don't want to limit the results to "last 30 days". Rather, January, December etc

Thanks!

Comment: Would [aggregation](http://drupal.org/node/1398368) help here? Or a [PHP Filter Criterion](http://drupal.org/project/viewsphpfilter)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the "archive" example view, which is provided by default (though disabled) as part of the views module.  It can be found under "Archive" on the admin/structure/views page.

This view groups the content created on the site by year and month; the contextual filter, filter criteria, and sort criteria are already configured and working correctly.  Study this example view and hopefully it will help you create what you want to do.

Comment: wow, after messing for half an hour with this I finally found the solution! Thanks a ton!!!